# How to manipulate Manifest.xml in Multi Device Hybrid App

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I am developing a mobile app by Multi Device Mobile App in VS 2013, since AndroidManifest.xml is generated from scratch in build process how can I set something in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the AndroidManifest.xml by placing your custom manifest at `res/native/android`. Use the generated version of the file in the `bld/Debug/platforms/android` folder after building a Debug configuration of the project for Android to configure settings such as custom intents.